# Labeling matrices tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Could you help me to draw what’s on the image?

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25}  \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

    }
    \hfill
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25}  \\ \hline
            &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} &   \\ \hline
            &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  &   \\ \hline
        \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
            & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
            &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &\cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

    }
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you want to keep the tables and just annotate them (rather than creating these grids with Ti*k*Z). Then a `local cs` (as e.g. defined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492275/121799)) can help you achieving this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[local cs/.style={shift={(#1.south west)},x={(#1.south
    east)-(#1.south west)},y={(#1.north west)-(#1.south west)}}]
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tab) {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25}  \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}};
        \begin{scope}[local cs=tab,font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
         \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([yshift=-1em]0,0)
         -- ([yshift=-1em]1,0) node[pos=5/12,below]{independent\\
         variables} node[pos=5/6,anchor=north west]{dependent\\
         variables};
         \draw[double=black,double distance=0.8pt,white,thick] (5/6,-0.2em) 
         -- ++(0,-1.6em);
         \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([xshift=1em]1,0) -- ([xshift=1em]1,1)
          node[pos=2/9,right]{test\\rows}
          node[pos=13/18,right]{training\\rows};
         \draw[double=black,double distance=0.8pt,white,thick]
         ([xshift=0.2em]1,4/9) -- ++ (1.6em,0);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    }
    \hfill
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[local cs/.style={shift={(#1.south west)},x={(#1.south
    east)-(#1.south west)},y={(#1.north west)-(#1.south west)}}]
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tab) {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25}  \\ \hline
            &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} &   \\ \hline
            &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  &   \\ \hline
        \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
            & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
            &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &\cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}};
        \begin{scope}[local cs=tab,font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
         \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([yshift=-1em]0,0)
         -- ([yshift=-1em]1,0) node[pos=1/2,below]{no demarcation between
         independent\\ and dependent variables};
         \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([xshift=1em]1,0) -- ([xshift=1em]1,1)
          node[pos=1/2,right]{no\\ demarcation\\ between\\ training and\\ test rows};
        \end{scope}
       \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! You nailed it! Such a pro. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you reduce the font size?

Comment: @Delan Sure, you can either replace `font=\sffamily,` by `font=\sffamily\small,` or `nodes={align=center}` by `nodes={align=center,scale=0.8}` (say) or combine the two options.

Comment: @marmot Always my compliments.

Comment: @marmot Hello! I am trying to put some captions on each table by changing the `\begin{table}` to `\begin{figure}` but it does not seem to be working; it throws many error. So far I can put a caption on the whole table, like this `\caption{Checking caption} \end{table}`. Is there any way I can add captions to each table and also to both tables as I they were a figure?

Comment: I am trying with `\begin[subtable}` and it seems to be woring!