# Local, relative, inner, intensive coordinate of one node

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, coordinates, relative

If often find myself writing:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (refNode) {\includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a}};

    % Boring way to define intensive coordinates relatively to it:
    \def\x{.2}  % e.g: "somewhat left"
    \def\y{.54} % e.g.: "slightly more than midway up"
    \coordinate (x) at ($(refNode.west)!\x!(refNode.east)$);   % boilerplate
    \coordinate (y) at ($(refNode.south)!\y!(refNode.north)$); % boilerplate
    \node[red] (intensively located) at (x |- y) {.};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: intense relative coordinates]

Is there not a simpler way to get this? Something like

```
\node[relatively to aNode=(.2, .54), red] (cool) {.};
```

Also, the above boilerplate extends correctly to coordinates outside of [0,1], but it is not enough if `refNode` happens to be `[rotate=34]`: it needs to become even more complicated then.

I am surprised I find no tikz builtin utility to do this kind of relative positionning.. have I missed anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You install basically a local coordinate system on the reference node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (refNode) {\includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a}};

    \begin{scope}[shift={(refNode.south west)},x={(refNode.south
    east)-(refNode.south west)},y={(refNode.north west)-(refNode.south west)}]
     \node[red] at (0.2,0.54) {.};
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And you can cast this in a style:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[local cs/.style={shift={(#1.south west)},x={(#1.south
    east)-(#1.south west)},y={(#1.north west)-(#1.south west)}}]

    \node (refNode) {\includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a}};

    \path[local cs=refNode] (0.2,0.54) node[red] {.};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is.. awesome! I'll `\tikzset` this in all my preambles from now on. Thank you :)